# Subfilter SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and want to sub filter my SQL query. I think an example is best. Below is sample data. Consider the `facode`, `DateStart`, and `stockQty` columns. I want to only return one row per unique `facode`. This should be based on the most recent `DateStart` value. The `stockQty` value returned should be the one linked to the `DateStart`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is what my current query returns:

```
artcode   | warehouse  |  facode | DateStart   | stockQty

 30003    | SM01       |  11111  | 4/5/2014    | 445
 30003    | SM01       |  11111  | 4/21/2014   | 1002
 30003    | SM01       |  11111  | 5/1/2014    | 385
 30003    | SM01       |  22222  | 3/23/2014   | 200
 30003    | SM01       |  22222  | 4/28/2014   | 350
 30003    | SM01       |  22222  | 4/29/2014   | 400
 30003    | SM01       |  33333  | 4/22/2014   | 125
 30003    | SM01       |  33333  | 5/3/2014    | 75   
 30003    | SM01       |  33333  | 5/5/2014    | 300
```

Here is what I want the query to return:

```
artcode   | warehouse|  facode |  DateStart  | stockQty

 30003    | SM01     |  11111  | 5/1/2014    | 385
 30003    | SM01     |  22222  | 4/29/2014   | 400 
 30003    | SM01     |  33333  | 5/5/2014    | 300
```

Below is my code:

```
    SELECT gbkmut.artcode
     , gbkmut.warehouse
     , gbkmut.facode
     , ItemNumbers.DateStart
     , ROUND(SUM(aantal),2) as stockQty
  FROM gbkmut
 INNER JOIN 
       ItemNumbers 
    ON gbkmut.artcode=Itemnumbers.Itemcode
 INNER JOIN Items as ic 
    ON ItemNumbers.ItemCode=ic.ItemCode
 INNER JOIN Items 
    on Items.GLAccountDistribution = gbkmut.reknr 
   AND gbkmut.artcode =Items.ItemCode 
   and items.type ='S' 
 WHERE gbkmut.transtype IN  ('X', 'N', 'C', 'P') 
   AND gbkmut.remindercount <> 999 
   AND artcode='30T30003'
 GROUP BY 
       gbkmut.warehouse
     , facode, artcode
     , items.costpricestandard
     , items.itemcode
     , itemnumbers.datestart
HAVING ROUND(SUM(aantal),2)>0.1
 ORDER BY 
       artcode
     , facode
     , gbkmut.warehouse
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes, you need to indicate which RDBMS. Otherwise you'll get COBOL code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * 
from 
(
    select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by artcode,warehouse , facode order by datestart desc) rn
    from 
    (
       -- your current query here
    ) src
) v
where rn = 1
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` is one way to do this.  Another option is to use `CROSS APPLY`, which is like a join to a correlated subquery.  You would write a subquery to return the data you need for a single `artcode` and `facode` - so you can use `TOP (1)` to get the row with the latest date - and then use `CROSS APPLY` to join it to gbkmut and deliver results for each relevant row.  Something like:

```
SELECT gbkmut.artcode, gbkmut.warehouse, gbkmut.facode, x.DateStart, x.stockQty
FROM gbkmut
CROSS APPLY (
    select top (1) g.facode, ItemNumbers.DateStart, ROUND(SUM(aantal),2) as stockQty
    from gbkmut g
    inner join ItemNumbers ON g.artcode=Itemnumbers.Itemcode
    INNER JOIN Items as ic ON ItemNumbers.ItemCode=ic.ItemCode
    INNER JOIN Items on Items.GLAccountDistribution = g.reknr 
        AND g.artcode =Items.ItemCode and items.type ='S'
    WHERE
    g.transtype IN  ('X', 'N', 'C', 'P')
     AND g.remindercount <> 999 
     AND artcode='30T30003'
     AND g.facode = gbkmut.facode
     AND gbkmut.artcode = g.artcode

    GROUP BY g.warehouse, g.facode, g.artcode
    HAVING ROUND(SUM(aantal),2)>0.1
    ORDER BY ItemNumbers.DateStart DESC
) x

ORDER BY artcode, facode, gbkmut.warehouse
```

[This page](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/) gives a good introduction to `APPLY`, and also discusses performance of `APPLY` and `row_count()`.  Which of the two options performs better will (as usual!) depend on your data.

Answer (score 0):

The query of podiluska(+1) can be made more readable using a CTE

```
With Ord AS (
  Select artcode
       , warehouse
       , facode
       , DateStart
       , stockQty
       , Last = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY artcode, warehouse, facode
                                   ORDER BY DateStart Desc)
  FROM   gbkmut
)
SELECT artcode
     , warehouse
     , facode
     , DateStart
     , stockQty
FROM   Ord
Where  Last = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70ddb/2) demo